Question about Binyanim – Hebrew linguistics
I've looked into lots of linguistic works and found discussion of the 7 Binyanim (verb patterns) in much of modern Hebrew linguistics and even going back before. Obviously verbs in Tanakh (and all of Hebrew, mostly) follow the Binyanim as well, but when were the binyanim "codified"? Who was the first person, if there is one, to write about them, define them, and/or name them? Or has it always just been consensus?
I know this is a niche question but I was wondering if anyone knew!
Todah Rabah

Welcome to MiYodeya Jonah and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

These terms are already used by Rashi: https://www.sefaria.org/Rashi_on_Genesis.9.21.1

Please don't be discouraged by this question's closure. This site doesn't deal with questions on the Hebrew language, except as it answers questions about Jewish life. You might want to ask your on the Linguistics stackexchange.

Also Rashi on this past week’s parashah Genesis 24:65

Thank you all for both the examples and for the feedback! I look forward to using this site
